# 12.04 Random sounds sometimes after startup

Tags: 12.04, sound, 64-bit, startup

I'm not quite sure what the sound is, but it has only started happening in the last two days. The only way I can describe it would be that it sounds like a wooden xylophone being tapped lightly. It will play at random intervals ranging between 1 second to a couple minutes for up to a half hour (from what I have noticed) after startup. If anybody has any ideas as to what is causing this or how to fix it I would appreciate it.

System information:

- Computer: Toshiba Satellite L655-S5160
- Audio Driver: Conexant Audio Driver(v4.119.0.60; 07-14-2010; 41.89M)

Comment: It could be helpful to add what laptop brand you have, sound card etc. I have similar issues at startup but however I only have a static crackly sound at start-up then it stops, but we might have the same problem so I'll try looking into it.

Comment: Thx for the tip, I hadn't thought to post that. I posted an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest updating your driver to the next version which could help, however I discussed your question with a more experienced Ask Ubuntu member on chat and this is what that member's opinion was on your question:

> I saw this one - no good idea. Looks like a looping system sound.
>   ALSA sound drivers reside in the kernel. It usually is hard stuff to replace these with proprietary ones.

The [audio dev ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ppa) was an idea suggested **HOWEVER (BIG DISCLAIMER)** more often than not this can **cause serious problems with your system** due to the fact that they are "in development" and not fully tested so if you do decide to try this, make sure you've got a full back-up and accept that things could break.

In short if this problem isn't causing you serious pain on the ears and I'd live with it until there is a major driver update which I'd install, however until then I personally wouldn't try the [audio dev ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ppa) as of yet as its quite risky.

I'd suggest you get the next major driver update and put a [bounty](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties) on your question afterwards if the problem persists and hopefully someone with more experience/knowledge about hardware and drivers will be able to help you out.